# Installing a Printer Driver in Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, drivers, printer

I have a new mac which is now running Snow Leopard, I live on campus at BYU in the dorms, I wanted to print to an on-campus printer but I was unable to download the printer driver from BYU.edu. I need to if there is a way to print from my computer.

Comment: This question is to localized and should be closed as such, however look at rewording it to something more along the lines of installing a printer driver in Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

I attend BYU and have a Mac too, so here's how I got it to work (on 10.6.1):

1. Go to http://software.byu.edu and log in with you BYU NetID and password.
2. Click on the "Software" tab towards the top of the page.
3. From the software popup menu, choose "Open Access Print Driver (Mac OS X)"
4. Download the driver and install it.

When you go to print, you'll see two new printers in your print dialog: `Campus_Black_and_White` and `Campus_Color`.  Use the one corresponding to your needs.  When you print something, a dialog will pop up (this can take a minute) where you'll enter your NetID and a job name.  This is what associates the job with your account so you can retrieve it when you go to a printer and swipe your card.

Comment: The BYU MUG (Mac Users' Group) also has a very helpful list for such topics. https://mac.byu.edu/mailman/listinfo/byumug-discuss

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide more details than just what you gave up there - what is the printer model? How are you connected to the network? Is there any network authentication involved? Do you have the IP address for the printer?

More information is DEFINITELY needed before we can help you, but your best bet is BYU's tech helpdesk.

In short - try your campus library.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do this is to go to the optional installs on the Snow Leopard disk, then install printer drivers. This will waste about 4 GB of space, but mean you can print to almost any printer without having to download drivers.

Normally, though, if you try to print to a specific printer you don't have drivers for, Snow Leopard will download the drivers (from the Apple servers). Your first step should be trying to connect to that printer to actually print something. This is the part the BYU helpdesk can help you with. If you want to try yourself, start with the Print and Fax preference, and try adding the printer you want to use.